# Addthis widget conflict with ember

Tags: jquery, ember.js, addthis

I have problem with addthis widget when apply ember 0.9.8.1 on my site. Could you please help me figure it out? I'm using windows 7 and testing with these browsers: firefox 13.0.1, ie 9, safari, chrome.

Please go to this link http://jsfiddle.net/kcjzw/205/
Then hover on compact (plus) icon. it will throw error in firebug

```
evar
TypeError: P[O] is undefined
[Break On This Error]

...";}else{if(a1.bro.saf){aM+="
";aM+="
AddTh...

menu116.js (line 2)
menu116.js (line 2)
addthis_ssh is not defined
[Break On This Error]

...";}else{if(a1.bro.saf){aM+="
";aM+="
AddTh...
```

Thank in advance.

Comment: I have no error at all. I'm using Chromium 18.0.1025.151

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding the following line to my page:

`window.addthis_translations = {};`

See my comments on the GitHub issue for more detail:

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1099#issuecomment-6757044